# CTest --build-and-test with --test-command option

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest, ctest

I use Ctest to run a bunch of google tests that I have registered using `add_test()`. Currently, these tests do not take any arguments. However, I want to give them all arguments (common to all, specifically `--gtest_output=xml`) while running `ctest`.

I heard that this is possible using that `--test-command` option, however, I see that we need to use `--test-command` along with `--build-and-test`. Is there an example for this usage?

Comment: Is there a good example for the usage of the --test-command option? This link has usage but it doesn't work: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2009-March/028066.html

Comment: I'm trying to achieve to exact same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The format for `ctest` arguments are specified in the CTest [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/ctest.1.html#build-and-test-mode) as such:

> ```
> ctest --build-and-test <path-to-source> <path-to-build>
>       --build-generator <generator>
>       [<options>...]
>       [--build-options <opts>...]
>       [--test-command <command> [<args>...]]
> ```

So, on Visual Studio for example, you could run test `Test1` from your build folder (using `..` for the *source* directory, and `.` for the *binary* directory):

```
ctest --build-and-test .. . --build-generator "Visual Studio 16 2019" --test-command Test1 --gtest_output=xml
```

As of CMake 3.17, you can now specify arguments to pass to CTest (and arguments for individual tests) in the CMake file where you define the test itself. The `CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS` variable takes a semicolon-delimited list of arguments to pass to CTest. So, sticking with the above example, you could do something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CTEST_ARGUMENTS "--build-and-test;${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR};${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR};--build-generator;${CMAKE_GENERATOR};--test-command;Test1;--gtest_output=xml")
```